# Sign any message with the user’s private key and verify the signature on Ethereum

Tags: ios, swift, ethereum, web3swift

I'm trying to explore Ethereum and creating a app which let user sign message and validate the message.
I'm using web3swift framework for this and what I have tried so far is as follows -

```
    let web3Rinkeby = Web3.InfuraRinkebyWeb3()
    let msgStr = "This is my first Ethereum App";
    let data = msgStr.data(using: .utf8)
    let signMsg = web3Rinkeby.wallet.signPersonalMessage(data!, account: address);

    print(signMsg);
```

but I'm not sure if this is right and how to validate any message as well. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Seems, that you didn't specify exact address.
Here is an example:

```
let web3Rinkeby = Web3.InfuraRinkebyWeb3()

/// 
    let keystore = try! EthereumKeystoreV3(password: "")
    let keystoreManager = KeystoreManager([keystore!])
    web3Rinkeby.addKeystoreManager(keystoreManager)
    let address = keystoreManager.addresses![0]
///

let msgStr = "This is my first Ethereum App";
let data = msgStr.data(using: .utf8)
let signMsg = web3Rinkeby.wallet.signPersonalMessage(data!, account: address);

print(signMsg);
```

Here is an example, how to sign transactions in the [tests of the project](https://github.com/matterinc/web3swift/blob/develop/web3swiftTests/web3swift_rinkeby_personalSignature_Tests.swift#L20):

Comment: how to maintain multiple wallet ,need to store separate key json file?

Comment: @jesuasir please, have a look `KeystoreManager` https://github.com/skywinder/web3swift/blob/5484e81580219ea491d48e94f6aef6f18d8ec58f/Sources/web3swift/KeystoreManager/KeystoreManager.swift